# Get Dynamic Image Url in MVC 4 Javascript using @url.content method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Following is the scenario for my case.

1. There is View which is strongly bind with IEnumerable of NewsVM.

   ```
   @model IEnumerable<ProjectName.Models.News.NewsVM>
   ```
2. Following is the View Model Name NewsVM.cs.

   ```
   public long news_sk { get; set; }
   public Nullable<int> user_fk { get; set; }
   public string title { get; set; }
   public string short_desc { get; set; }
   public string full_desc { get; set; }
   public string source_link { get; set; } //This can be either local content path or online url
   public string type { get; set; }
   public Nullable<System.DateTime> created_time { get; set; }
   public Nullable<bool> isactive { get; set; }
   public int SectionID { get; set; }
   public string UserImage { get; set; }
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   //Method which will fetch data from DB and populate in this VM and gererate IList<NewsVM> and return it to controller action.
   public static IList<NewsVM> GetNews(int LastID = 0){......}
   ```
3. Here is controller action method.

   ```
   public JsonResult GetNextNewsContent(int ID)
   {
       IList<NewsVM> lstNewsContentBM = NewsVM.GetNews(ID);
       return Json(lstNewsContentBM, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ```
4. Here is the View. I am calling GetNextNewsContent from Jquery code with $.ajax method and receiving Json response as result.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(window).scroll(function () {
   if ($(document).height() <= $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) {
       //alert("End Of The Page");
       //alert($('#LastContentID').val());
       GetNextContents(($('#LastContentID').val()))
   }
   });

   function GetNextContents(LastID) {
   debugger;
   var ID = LastID;
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: 'News/GetNextNewsContent/' + ID,
       success: function (item, status) {
           debugger;
           var appenstring = "";
           for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
            appenstring =  "<div class='NewsContainer'>"; 
            appenstring += "<div class='NewsContainer-Userdeails'>";
            appenstring += "<div id='' class='NewsContainer-UserImage'>"
                   if (item[i].UserImage != null && item[i].UserImage.length > 0)
                   {
                       appenstring += "<img src='http://test.clearcellgroup.co.uk:82/Images/Members/'"+ item[i].UserImage + "alt='Image Not found' height='70px' width='50px'/>";
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       appenstring += "<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/BlankUserImg-small.png")' alt='Image Not found' height='70px' width='50px' />";
                   }
               appenstring += "</div>";
               appenstring += "<div class='NewsContainer-UserName'>"+item[i].UserName + "</div>";

           appenstring += "</div>";
           appenstring += "<table style='clear: both;'><tr>";
                   appenstring += "<td valign='top'>";
                       appenstring += "<div class='NewsContainer-Header'>"+ item[i].title + "</div>";
                       appenstring += "<div class='NewsContainer-desc'> <p>"+ item[i].short_desc + "</p>";
                       appenstring += "</div>";
                   appenstring += "</td>";
               appenstring += "</tr>";
               appenstring +="<tr>";
                   appenstring +="<td>";
                       if (item[i].type.toLowerCase() == "video")
                       {
                           appenstring +="<div class='ShadowBorder NewsContainer-div-iframe'>";
                           appenstring +="<iframe class='NewsContainer-iframe' scrolling='no' src='" + item[i].source_link +"'></iframe> </div>";

                       }
                       else if (item[i].type.toLowerCase() == "image")
                       {
                           appenstring +="<div class='ShadowBorder NewsContainer-div-iframe'>";
                           **appenstring +="<img src='@Url.Content(item[i].source_link)'** /></div>";
                       }
                       else if (item[i].type.toLowerCase() == "link")
                       {
                           appenstring +="<div class='ShadowBorder NewsContainer-div-iframe'>";
                           appenstring +="<a href='" + item[i].source_link+ "' target='_blank'>" + item[i].source_link +"</a></div>";
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           appenstring +="<div class='ShadowBorder NewsContainer-div-iframe'><span>No Content</span></div>";                                    

                       }
                   appenstring +="</td>";
               appenstring +="</tr>";
           appenstring +="</table>";
       appenstring +="</div>";
       debugger;
               if (item[i].SectionID == 1)
               {
                   $('#Section1').append(appenstring);
               }
               else if (item[i].SectionID == 2)
               {
                  $('#Section2').append(appenstring);         
               }
               else if (item[i].SectionID == 0)
               {
                  $('#Section0').append(appenstring);       
               }
               else
               {
                   //appenstring +="<div class='ShadowBorder NewsContainer-div-iframe'><span>No Content</span></div>";                                    
               }
           }
       },
       error: function (error, status) {
           alert("error");
       }

   });
   }
   ```

   I want to load image which is in images folder of server. How can i get the path of server folder in Jquery code. I have tryed this `'@Url.Content(item[i].source_link)'` but didn't work because `item[i].source_link` is not available at compile time and `@Url.Content` is getting resolved at compile time.

So Is there any other way i can achieve the same..???
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: I will recommend you to create a PartialView and return PartialViewResult

Comment: How can i do it for my current scenario can you explain.. If you can explain it with some sample code then it would be very help ful..